# How to get the Start of day and End of Day in UTC Conversation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timezone, datetime-conversion

Hello I am trying to Start of Day

Like in India TimeZone

- **Start of Day is: 2022-11-20 00:00:00 (local time in India)**
- **In UTC: 2022-11-20 05:30:00 PM**

Comment: the UTC time at the day start in India (local time 0:00)

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDate                                      // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day, without time zone or offset.
.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )            // Capture the current date as seen in a particular time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. 
.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )   // Determine the first moment of the day. May or may not be 00:00. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toInstant()                                   // Adjust to an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Returns an `Instant` object.
.toString()                                    // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format. Returns a `String` object, containing formatted text.
```

> 2022-11-19T18:30:00Z

## Details

Capture the current date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Get the first moment of that day. Do *not* assume the day starts at 00:00. Some days on some dates in some time zones start at a different time of day such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

To view that same moment through the wall-clock time of UTC (an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds), extract an `Instant`. An `Instant` represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as seen in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

See that code run at Ideone.com.

```
today.toString(): 2022-11-20
zdt.toString(): 2022-11-20T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
instant.toString(): 2022-11-19T18:30:00Z
```

To generate text in various formats, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) rather than [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). The `Instant` class is a basic building-block class in *java.time*. The `OffsetDateTime` class is more flexible, including features for generating text in formats other than standard ISO 8601 format.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

To learn more about generating text, [search Stack Overflow](https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3AStackOverflow.com%20java%20DateTimeFormatter&search=&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20datetimeformatter&sc=0-45&qs=n&sk=&cvid=452BC129497642849DD0BF33AE65D3CD&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&ghpl=) for existing Questions and Answers about [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

---

Java 8+ comes with an implementation of *java.time*. Ditto for Android 26+. For earlier Android, the latest tooling provides most of the *java.time* functionality via “API desugaring”.

Comment: But it works above Android Oreo. what about below version Devices

Comment: @Arjunsaini See edits, at bottom of the Answer.

Comment: @user16320675 No, I do not recommend that approach. The result is a `ZonedDateTime`, which works technically but is misleading. A date-time object with a mere offset rather than a time zone should use `OffsetDateTime`. For a UTC-only value, `Instant` is appropriate where you do not need flexibility such as generating text in various formats.

Comment: @user16320675 May I suggest a compromise? :-) An `OffsetDateTime` has the advantage over `Instant` that it can be formatted (like when the OP asked for `2022-11-20 05:30:00 PM`). We don’t want a `ZonedDateTIme`.

Comment: @user16320675 & @OleV.V. Thanks to your comments, I added a bit about using `OffsetDateTime` to generate text in flexible formats.